# how to print a category with sub-list (courses). java

Tags: java, list, object

I have two classes One Category and one Course they have a common identifier int categoryId. Each category has one course. I want to print each category with its related course. the category object contains course list as a parameter so when i print out the category for each element all elements of courses are printed repeatedly which not suppose to.

```
public class Category {

private int categoryId;
private String name;
private String description;

private List<Course> courseList;

public Category(int categoryId, String name, String description,List<Course> courseList) {

    this.categoryId = categoryId;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.courseList = courseList;
}


public int getCategoryId() {
    return categoryId;
}

public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public List<Course> getCourseList() {
    return courseList;
}

public void setCourseList(List<Course> courseList) {
    this.courseList = courseList;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Category{" +
            "categoryId=" + categoryId +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", description='" + description + '\'' +
            ", courseList=" + courseList +
            '}';
}
```

}

```
public class Course {

private int courseId;
private int categoryId;
private String name;
private int duration;
private int miles;
  
public int getCourseId() {
    return courseId;
}

public void setCourseId(int courseId) {
    this.courseId = courseId;
}

public int getCategoryId() {
    return categoryId;
}

public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public void setDuration(int duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}

public int getMiles() {
    return miles;
}

public void setMiles(int miles) {
    this.miles = miles;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Course{" +
            "courseId=" + courseId +
            ", categoryId=" + categoryId +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", duration=" + duration +
            ", miles=" + miles + '}';
}
```

}

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){



    List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new Course(2001, 1001, "Cloud Computing",180, 200),
            new Course(2002, 1002, "Web servers Computing",200, 250))
    );


   List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
           new Category(1001, "AWS", "cloud courses", courses),
    new Category(1002, "LMS", "English courses", courses))
   );


  for(Category c : categories){
        for(Course cr: courses){
            if(c.getCategoryId() == cr.getCategoryId()){

                System.out.println(c);
            }

        }

    }
```

}

The output:

> Category{categoryId=1001, name='AWS', description='cloud courses',
> courseList=[courseId=2001, name='Cloud Computing', duration=180,
> miles=200}, courseId=2002, name='Web servers Computing', duration=200,
> miles=250}]} Category{categoryId=1002, name='LMS', description='engish
> courses', courseList=[courseId=2001, name='Cloud Computing',
> duration=180, miles=200}, courseId=2002, name='Web servers Computing',
> duration=200, miles=250}]}

Comment: The output matches what you have in memory. You need two nested loops, one iterates over the categories and the other iterates over the courses. In addition, your println() outputs the whole category object which includes all coursed because you created it this way. I think that your input data structure does not make sense.

Comment: Thanks Stefan for your comment, I already did nested loop however, the problem is course list in included as a parameter in category list so I did not know how to call only the course that related to the course through categoryId which is a parameter in both course and category objects.